# Building URDF from scratch, how to calculate inertial values?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been stuck on this for a while. Most resources online point to complex equations even for the simplest of shapes. Surely there is some sort of software in which I can just build my robot and have it generate inertial values?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260570/building-urdf-from-scratch,-how-to-calculate-inertial-values?/) by [Auton0mous](https://answers.ros.org/users/29134/auton0mous/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2017-04-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-04-28**:
I don't know of any software that would "just" do this for you unfortunately. But to make sure: if you are not planning on using any sort of dynamic simulator (Gazebo, V-REP, etc), you don't need to specify any inertial properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've found the following link to be very helpful: http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=inertia

And I actually just make my inertial values the same as a box the same size as my collision shapes so the inertial values are just calculated using the formula lists for cuboids on this [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia) using the values from my collision boxes. Like that gazebo tutorial mentions, if you temporarily set mass = 1, you can view the inertial cube in gazebo and it should be the same as your collision cube.

This is close enough for most applications.

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2017-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check out the [MyBot Tutorial](https://github.com/HumaRobotics/mybot_gazebo_tutorial) and specifically its [xacro file](https://github.com/HumaRobotics/mybot_gazebo_tutorial/blob/master/mybot_description/urdf/macros.xacro) :

```
<macro name="cylinder_inertia" params="m r h">
      <inertia  ixx="${m*(3*r*r+h*h)/12}" ixy = "0" ixz = "0"
                  iyy="${m*(3*r*r+h*h)/12}" iyz = "0"
                  izz="${m*r*r/2}" /> 
      </macro>

<macro name="box_inertia" params="m x y z">
        <inertia  ixx="${m*(y*y+z*z)/12}" ixy = "0" ixz = "0"
                  iyy="${m*(x*x+z*z)/12}" iyz = "0"
                  izz="${m*(x*x+z*z)/12}" /> 
</macro>

<macro name="sphere_inertia" params="m r">
        <inertia  ixx="${2*m*r*r/5}" ixy = "0" ixz = "0"
                  iyy="${2*m*r*r/5}" iyz = "0"
                  izz="${2*m*r*r/5}" /> 
</macro>
```

These macroses are calculations for basic shapes and could be easily pulled into your project. But if you need inertias for some custom shapes, then you should look into some 3D modeling SW, they have capability to calculate necessary matrices for you.

---

Originally posted by [spooner-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/29765/spooner-dev/) with karma: 151 on 2017-04-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I implemented a python script reading an 3D file like **stl** or **dae** and outputting the **full URDF XML inertial tag** based on the *gazebosim* [tutorial.](https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=inertia)

At first the script calculates the center of mass of the object. After that it scales the mesh by a factor of 100 to increase the numerical accuracy. You could manually change that, if you need to scale it more up. Now the convex hull of your object will be calculated. For the hull the geometric properties will be calculated, scaled back down and outputted as URDF XML inertial tag like that (the precision could also be changed in the script)

```
<inertial>
  <origin xyz="0.00000002 -0.00000001 0.00000000"/>
  <mass value="5.00000000"/>
  <inertia ixx="7.90866056" ixy="0.00000006" ixz="0.00000000" iyy="7.90866060" iyz="0.00000000" izz="2.48398783"/>
</inertial>
```

Check it out here: https://github.com/vonunwerth/MeshLabInertiaToURDF

---

Originally posted by [vonunwerth](https://answers.ros.org/users/34864/vonunwerth/) with karma: 66 on 2022-06-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1